# Handling receiving multiple messages / multiple chunks when using websockets in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I'm implementing a websocket server and using binary data (not text) to communicate between server and clients. When waiting for a message to receive and then process should I care about a message received in multiple chunks and also two messages receives at the same time when I use following code?

```
var buffer = new byte[256];
var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
```

*I'm sure all messages sent by (valid) clients/server are fitted within 256 bytes long buffer and EndOfMessage flag is set to true when using webSocket.SendAsync();

If yes, I would be grateful to see a best practice code that handles receiving messages properly when there is a "await Process(byte[] data)" method that handles only one message at a time.

I used following code to handle messages with multiple chunks but not sure whether it is overengineering or not.

```
while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    var buffer = new byte[256];
    await using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
    do
    {
        result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            return;
        }
        await dataStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
    } while (!result.EndOfMessage);
    await Process(dataStream.ToArray()); //Process functions do not detect multiple messages, and just can process one message at a time
    dataStream.SetLength(0); //Clear memory stream data
}
```

Comment: "*I used following code to handle messages with multiple chunks but not sure whether it is overengineering or not.*" -- nah, that looks fairly standard. It might be fine just to use a single buffer however (depending on whether you know your maximum message length): just adjust the `ArraySegment` to point to the bit of the buffer which you've filled with data so far

Comment: Looks fine except that you might want to move `await using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();` to the outside of the loop so you are not recreating it every time. You would then also need to do `dataStream.Position = 0;` after clearing it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would be grateful to see a best practice code that handles receiving messages properly

Not sure about best practice, but regarding comments above i would make some refactoring:

```
var buffer = new Memory<byte>(new byte[256]);    

while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    ValueWebSocketReceiveResult result;
    do
    {
        result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            return;
        }            
    } 
    while (!result.EndOfMessage);        
    //Process functions do not detect multiple messages, and just can process one message at a time
    await Process(buffer[..result.Count]); // range op for Memory<byte> is quite cheap         
}
```

So, changes made:

1. `byte[]` replaced with `Memory<byte>()` for reason `Range` operator usages (`buffer[..result.Count]`) will not cause memory allocations on that type.
2. Other overload of `socket.ReceiveAsync()` is used returning `ValueTask<WebSocketReceiveResult>` (not `Task<>`), so, 8 bytes economy per call for memory allocations, afaik.
3. If messages are not exactly of 256 size, but falls within that range, we must consider `result.Count`
4. Interesting part: as data is handled **sequentially** we can use Memory further, and no need in `MemoryStream` at all.

   4.2. If we wanna get more bandwidth for this piece of logic, we can't get rid of `MemoryStream` and have to use extra allocation to copy data for `Process(..)` method call.
   Code would be a bit different:

   ```
   var buffer = new Memory<byte>(new byte[256]);
   await using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();

   while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
   {
       ValueWebSocketReceiveResult result;
       do
       {
           result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
           if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
           {
               await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
               return;
           }
           await dataStream.WriteAsync(buffer[..result.Count]);
       } while (!result.EndOfMessage);
       //Process asynchronously, so we don't wait 
       //but have to handle all of the branches there: normal/error/cancelled
       // have to make extra allocation for data copy
       _ = Process(dataStream.ToArray());
       dataStream.SetLength(0); //Clear memory stream data
   }
   ```

**PS**: If you know your message sizes (in this simple case - your protocol), it is possible to get rid of `while (!result.EndOfMessage);` instruction. It would be quite unreliable, but just to point out for the best bandwidth case.